# how to run the powershell script with 2 foreach in c#

Tags: c#

This is the powershell script I want to run in c# :

```
ForEach ($Mailbox in Get-Mailbox) {Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox 
$Mailbox.Identity –ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
SelectDeviceFriendlyName,Devicetype,DeviceUserAgent | ForEach-Object { $_ | Add-Member –
MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MailboxIdentity" -value $Mailbox}}
```

I could complete the c# coding upto first foreach loop in powershell script, but I do not know how implement the 2nd foreach that uses $mailbox variable along with the coding given below.

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox"); 
command.AddCommand("where-object"); 
command.AddParameter("Filterscript", ScriptBlock.Create("!$_.name.startswith   \"DiscoverySearchMailbox\")")); 
powershell.Commands = command;
powershell.Runspace = CreateRunSpace.GetRunSpace();
var result = powershell.Invoke();
```

```
PSCommand command1 = new PSCommand(); 
command1.AddCommand("write-output"); 
command1.AddParameter("InputObject", result); 
command1.AddCommand("Foreach-Object");
command1.AddParameter("Process", ScriptBlock.Create("Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $_.Identity")); 
powershell.Commands = command1;
powershell.Runspace = 
CreateRunSpace.GetRunSpace(); 
var result1 = powershell.Invoke();
```

I'm stuck at 2nd foreach loop to add-member while adding the output of get-mailbox. 
Appreciate your help and suggestions in advance. Thank you.

Comment: You've forgotten to explain what the problem is, or to actually ask a question. "I'm stuck at 2nd foreach loop" is not a description of a problem, and "Requesting your help" is not a question. Please [edit] your post to add those things. (And please don't add back the **bold**, and don't use tag information in your subject.)